# why this error in my code "TypeError: None is not valid value for the expected return type integer "

Tags: binary-search

a simple binary search question:
find target in list `nums` , if not found `return -1`

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        def bin(l,r):
            mid = l + (r-l)//2
            if mid == target and l <= r:
                return mid
            elif nums[mid] > target and l<=r:
                bin(l,mid-1)
            elif nums[mid] < target and l <= r:
                bin(mid+1,r)
            elif l > r :
                return (-1)
        
        z = bin(0,len(nums)-1)
        return z        
lass Solution:
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        def bin(l,r):
            mid = l + (r-l)//2
            if mid == target and l <= r:
                return mid
            elif nums[mid] > target and l<=r:
                bin(l,mid-1)
            elif nums[mid] < target and l <= r:
                bin(mid+1,r)
            elif l > r :
                return (-1)
        
        z = bin(0,len(nums)-1)
        return z
```